# How to create 0/1 DataFrame based on two other DataFrame with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to create a DataFrame `df3` based on two other DataFrames `df1` and `df2`. If the value in `df1` is bigger or equal the value in `df2`, then I want to assign a 1 in `df3` and otherwise a 0.

This would be a sample data for illustration:

```
df1
    Date        01K  02K  03K   04K
0   2021-01-01  NaN  3.5  4.2   NaN
1   2021-01-02  2.3  0.1  5.2   2.6
2   2021-01-03  0.3  NaN  2.5   8.2
3   2021-01-04  0.4  NaN  3.0   4.2

df2
    Date        01K  02K  03K   04K
0   2021-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1   2021-01-02  2.5  0.6  5.8   2.3
2   2021-01-03  0.2  NaN  2.5   8.1
3   2021-01-04  0.3  NaN  2.8   4.2

df3
    Date        01K  02K  03K   04K
0   2021-01-01  0    0    0     0
1   2021-01-02  0    0    0     1
2   2021-01-03  1    0    1     1
3   2021-01-04  1    0    1     1
```

For reproducibility:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K':['NaN', 2.3, 0.3, 0.4], 
    '02K':[3.5, 0.1, 'NaN', 'NaN'], 
    '03K':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0], 
    '04K':['NaN', 2.6, 8.2, 4.2]}) 
df1 = df1.replace('NaN',np.nan)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K':['NaN', 2.5, 0.2, 0.3], 
    '02K':['NaN', 0.6, 'NaN', 'NaN'], 
    '03K':['NaN', 5.8, 2.5, 2.8], 
    '04K':['NaN', 2.3, 8.1, 4.2]}) 
df2 = df2.replace('NaN',np.nan)
```

I tried to do it with np.where(), but I get an array as output.

```
df3 = np.where(df1>=df2, 1, 0)

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Is there an efficient way to create `df3` with the same structure as the other DataFrames for a big dataset?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Date` to `DatetimeIndex` in both, so possible compare with casting ouput to integers for map `True, False`s to `1, 0`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

df3 = (df1>=df2).astype(int)
```

If need instead `1` using `-1` use:

```
df3 = (df1>=df2).astype(int).mul(-1)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1>=df2, -1, 0), 
                  index=df1.index, 
                  columns=df1.columns)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your fast reply! Just in case I want to assign a -1 instead of 1, is there also a simple way?

Comment: Many thanks, it might also be interesting to know how to use several conditions in np.where(): If df1>df2 then 1, if df1=df2 then 0 (also for NaN cases), if df1<df2 then -1.

Comment: @fjurt - Then use `np.select` instead `np.where`